# XSL\C# - Why xsl:template add lines in output

Tags: c#, xslt

I use xslt file to write files in text mode (xsl:output method="text").

This xslt is transform via C# code.

My xslt is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:utils="urn:myExtension" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <!-- Déclaration du format de sortie (texte) -->
    <xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />

    <!-- Modèle principal -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        test
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is like this, with newline and space at end :

```
        test
```

My question is why newline are added to the output ? It's like if the "<xsl:template>" itself and the indent of the xslt are take into the output.
Is it possible to change this ?

I don't want that tags are taken to indent text.

If I write my template like this :
`<xsl:template match="/">test</xsl:template>`

or like this :

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>test</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
```

It's ok, the result is
`test`

But I have a lot of "<xsl:value-of select" inside text so do I have to put "<xsl:text>" each time I need  ?

My C# is like this :

```
var xsltSettings = new XsltSettings(false, true);
var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
transform.Load(xsltFile, xsltSettings, new XmlUrlResolver());

transform.Transform(xmlFile, outputFile);
```

I tried with a XmlWriter and same result

```
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(outputFile, transform.OutputSettings))
{
    transform.Transform(xmlFile, writer);
}
```

Hope to be clear.

Comment: You literally put that text node with the line breaks and white space around the word "test" inside of the `xsl:template`, so why do you expect the letters or the word to show up in the output but the white space not? As you have found, you can use `xsl:text` to control the formatting better while also formatting/indenting your XSLT code.

Comment: *"I have a lot of "<xsl:value-of select" inside text"* Then post a question about that, with a relevant example.

Comment: Ok, I didn't understand that tag was used in indenting.

So I have to use xsl:text. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general rule is that text nodes in a stylesheet that consist entirely of whitespace are ignored, but whitespace which is part of a text node that also contains printable text is treated as being significant. You've already found the remedy: use `xsl:text`.